# python - dictionary iterator for pool map

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am handling set of frozensets. I am trying to find minimal sets for each frozenset in the dictionary 'output'. I have 70k frozensets, so i am making chunk of this frozenset dictionary and parallelizing this task. When i try to pass this dictionary as an input to my function, only key is being sent and so i am getting error, can someone help me to find what's wrong in this.

```
output => {frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0}

def reduce(prob,result,output):
    print(output)
    for k in output.keys():
    #Function to do something


def reducer(prob,result,output):
    print(output)
    p = Pool(4) #number of processes = number of CPUs
    func2 = partial(reduce,prob,result)
    reduced_values= p.map( func2,output,chunksize=4)
    p.close() # no more tasks
    p.join()  # wrap up current tasks
    return reduced_values

if __name__ == '__main__':
    final = reducer(prob,result,output)

{frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0}
frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}) 
Error : AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

### Updated as requested

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import itertools

output = {frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0}
prob = {'3': 0.3, '1': 0.15, '2': 0.5, '4': 0.05}
result = {'2': {frozenset({'time', 'zone'}), frozenset({'time', 'rfid'})}, '3': {frozenset({'time', 'rfid'}), frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'})}}

def reduce(prob,result,output):
    print(output)
    for k in output.keys():
        for ky,values in result.items():
            if any(k>=l for l in values):
                output[k] += sum((j for i,j in prob.items() if i == ky))
    return output


def reducer(prob,result,output):
    print(output)
    p = Pool(4) #number of processes = number of CPUs
    func2 = partial(reduce,prob,result)
    reduced_values= p.map( func2,output,chunksize=4)
    p.close() # no more tasks
    p.join()  # wrap up current tasks
    return reduced_values

if __name__ == '__main__':
    final = reducer(prob,result,output)


{frozenset({'zone', 'rfid'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'time', 'zone'}): 0}
    for k in output.keys():
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'keys'
frozenset({'zone', 'rfid'})
```

### Full error details from the console:

```
{frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'rfid'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0}
frozenset({'zone', 'time'})
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "F:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\Dell\workspace\key_mining\src\variable.py", line 16, in reduce
    for k in output.keys():
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'keys'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\variable.py", line 33, in <module>
    final = reducer(prob,result,output)
  File "C:\***\variable.py", line 27, in reducer
    reduced_values= p.map( func2,output,chunksize=4)
  File "F:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "F:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: When you apply `p.map` to a dictionary, it treats it like a list, and therefore iterates over the keys just like a for loop would. Do you want to pass it `output.items()` and do something with each of those tuples?

Comment: I want the whole dictionary output => {frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0} inside that function, then i want to iterate on each key, values. But my doubt here is when i tried to print output inside that function, i am getting only this frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}) , not frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0. Thats where the problem is.. :(

Comment: @Jeeva please check where your `output` variable changed to `output.keys()`. That is the error. Somehow your output variable changed before it passed to function.

Comment: Updated the full code.. Please check

Comment: @Jeeva traceback still missing what you get in console. Please copy past what you get in console without editing.

Comment: You will get the same error if you execute the same code in your machine.. But anyways, updated it for you now.. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a `dict` object to `map`. When `map` iterates over the items in `output`, it's doing this:

```
for key in output:  # When you iterate over a dictionary, you just get the keys.
    func2(key)
```

So each time `func2` is called, all that's contained in `output` is a single key (a `frozenset`) from the dictionary.

Based on your comments above, it seems you want to pass the entire dictionary to `func2`, but if you do that, you're really not doing anything at all in parallel. I think maybe you think that doing

```
pool.map(func2, output, chunksize=4)
```

Will result in the `output` dictionary being split into four dictionaries, each chunk being passed to an instance of `func2`. But that's not what happens at all. Instead, each key from the dictionary is sent individually `func2`.

`chunksize` is just used to tell the `pool` how many elements of `output` to send to each child process via inter-process communication at a time. It's only used for internal purposes; no matter what `chunksize` you use, `func2` will only be called with a single element of `output`.

If you want to actually pass chunks of the dict, you need to do something like this:

```
# Break the output dict into 4 lists of (key, value) pairs
items = list(output.items())
chunksize = 4
chunks = [items[i:i + chunksize ] for i in range(0, len(items), chunksize)]
reduced_values= p.map(func2, chunks)
```

That will pass a list of `(key, value)` tuples from the `output` dict to `func2`. Then, inside `func2`, you can turn the list back into a dict:

```
def reduce(prob,result,output):
    output = dict(item for item in output)  # Convert back to a dict
    print(output)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. My understanding with chunksize was wrong, thanks for clarifying. Could you please clarify why 'chunks' was not at all used anywhere in p.map? And i guess we need to use chunks in the place of output in reduced_values= p.map( func2,output,chunksize=4) ? And i am getting this error    chunks = [items[i:i + chunksize ] for i in range(0, len(items), chunksize)]
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Jeeva I've edited my answer to fix those issues. I should have passed `chunks` to `pool.map`, not `output`. And in Python 3 `dict.items()` doesn't return a list, it returns a dict view, which isn't what we want, so I explicitly cast it to a `list`.

Comment: Yeah. It works and thanks for explaining instead of just giving the answers. Thats helping a lot to learn.. :) Just a curiosity to understand, making list will take more memory than any other datatype, isnt it? Is it possible to create a tuple or anything other datatype irrespective of list casting?

Comment: This is giving me set of dictionaries in a list like this [{frozenset({'zone', 'rfid'}): 0.35, frozenset({'zone', 'time', 'rfid'}): 1.0}, {frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'time'}): 0}] how to make it a single dictionary?

Comment: @Jeeva Iterate over the list of dicts and combine them by calling `update` on a single merged dict: `final_dict = {]; for d in reduced_values: final_dict.update(d)`

Comment: Thanks. I have written a piece of code for this. But yours seems to be efficient, let me try. thanks again.. :)

Comment: I am getting error.. :( dict has no attribute 'update'

Comment: @Jeeva `dict` objects definitely have an `update` function. I did make a typo above, though. `final_dict = {]` should be `final_dict = {}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61643/discussion-between-jeeva-and-dano).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, you are trying to access `frozenset.keys` in `output.keys()`.

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) are used to perform set operation like `UNION`, `INTERSECTION` etc.

When you pass arg in `frozenset` it convert it to `frozenset` object and `frozenset` has no method `keys` which you are trying to access @ `for k in output.keys():` when you passed `output` in `reducer you passed output it might have only`output.keys`like`[frozenset({...}), frozenset({...})]`, when you try to access`output.keys()`means`frozenset({...}).keys` its give error.

Comment: `{'rfid', 'zone'}` is not a dictionary literal. It's a set literal.

Comment: yes. I am not passing frozenset. I am passing dictionary which is having 'frozenset as keys' as an iterable argument to p.map.

Comment: How come it is frozenset.keys ?? As you see above, i am passing 'output' -- dictionary as the iterator. If you can see the data, output has this => {frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone'}): 0, frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): 0}

Comment: @Lafada Yes, i can understand. But i am using output.keys() because output is my dictionary which is the one i am passing to that function. I am not using frozenset.keys and i am wondering why i am getting only this frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}) , not frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'}): 0 inside the function

Comment: No, i tried to print output from reducer function, i am getting the whole dictionary not only the keys..

Comment: @Jeeva Whole function means ? you are not getting same output variable?

Comment: @Jeeva now need full traceback to understand where the `output` variable changed. Please past full tranceback in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61600/discussion-between-jeeva-and-lafada).